# Catch date: invalid date

Tags: bash, date

Within a function a date string should be parsed.

```bash
function my_func {
    DATE_DIFF=$(( ($(date -d $1 +%s) - $(date +%s)) / 86400))
    echo $DATE_DIFF
    ...
}
```

Problem is that the given date is a user given entry and if something like this `2022-11-02,some-value` is given (from CSV file) the date is invalid and `date: invalid date` is printed.

```bash
$ my_func 2022-11-02,some-value
date: invalid date ‘2022-11-02,some-value’
-19298
```

Somehow the variable `DATE_DIFF` is now `-19298`.

How can I detect an invalid date?

Comment: if `some-value`  includes `hms` such as `12:34:00`, modify the `date` command as `$(date -d "$1" +%s)` and call the function with `my_func "2022-11-02 12:34:00"`. Enclose the arguments with double quotes putting a whitespace, not a comma, in between.

Comment: Unfortunately not. `some-value` is only a string/comment

Comment: Then obviously, you *shouldn't* include the string in the arguments to `date` command.

Comment: Since `date` writes the error message to stderr, you can collect the stderr from the date command and if it is not-zero, you can infer that the format is wrong. Another possibility would be to evaluate the exit code (it is non-zero if there is an error). A third possibility is to first check the content of `$1` for correctness (using a bash regexp).

Comment: @user1934428, good suggestions, but [the range of valid inputs to `-d` date parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html) is really too complicated to be captured in a regex

Comment: @glennjackman : In general, yes. This would apply if the OP allows any valid ISO date specification. In practice, however, programs often expect from the user the date in a certain, narrowly defined format. If this is the case here - which only the OP can decide - parsing with a regex indeed would be a feasible approach. In particular since the OP, according to his comment above, allows free text inside the date  string (_some-value_), a regexp would help fiddling out that part which indeed denotes the date.

Comment: @glennjackman : Of course the whole question suffers from the sad fact, that the problem specification is unclear. The OP never explained, how the content of `$1` actually can look like.....

Answer (score 2):

To return early, you need to act on the exit status of the `date` command:

```bash
my_func() {
    local d1 d2
    d1=$(date -d "$1" +%s) || return 1
    d2=$(date -d "$2" +%s) || return 1
    echo $((d1 - d2))
}
```

The `local` declaration and the variable assignment must be on separate lines, otherwise the exit status of `local` overrides the exit status of `date`.

Then:

```bash
$ diff=$(my_func "2022-01-02 09:53:00" "2022-01-02 09:51:30") && echo $diff || echo "could not get date diff"
90
$ diff=$(my_func "2022-01-02 09:53:00" "2022-01-02 09:51:xx") && echo $diff || echo "could not get date diff"
date: invalid date ‘2022-01-02 09:51:xx’
could not get date diff
```